# How to create Firebase rule to check user properties

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I've added some custom properties to a node in Firebase. It's like;

```
{
  "user" : {
    "UID11" : {
      "address" : "address of user 1",
      "siteLink" : "site1",
      "subSiteLink" : "subsite1",  
    },
    "UID12" : {
      "address" : "address of user 2",
      "siteLink" : "site1"  
      "subSiteLink" : "subsite2",  
    }
    "UID21" : {
      "address" : "address of user 2",
      "siteLink" : "site2"  
      "subSiteLink" : "subsite2",  
    }
  }
}
```

And, there are site nodes. It's like;

```
{
  "site1" : {
     "subsite1" : {
         "someproperty" : "somevalue",
         "someproperty2" : "someValue"
      },
      "subsite2" : {
         "someproperty" : "somevalue",
         "someproperty2" : "someValue"
      },
      "general1" : {
         "someproperty" : "somevalue",
         "someproperty2" : "someValue"
      },
      "general2" : {
         "someproperty" : "somevalue",
         "someproperty2" : "someValue"
      }
    }

   "site2" : {
     "subsite1" : {
         "someproperty" : "somevalue",
         "someproperty2" : "someValue"
      },
      "subsite2" : {
         "someproperty" : "somevalue",
         "someproperty2" : "someValue"
      },
      "general1" : {
         "someproperty" : "somevalue",
         "someproperty2" : "someValue"
      },
      "general2" : {
         "someproperty" : "somevalue",
         "someproperty2" : "someValue"
      }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to create some rules. Users can access only their own subsite, and only general* nodes which is in a site which user has access. Here is an example according to above info;

**UID11** has access **site1.subsite1, site1.general1, site1.general2**.
**UID12** has access **site1.subsite2, site1.general1, site1.general2**.
**UID21** has access **site2.subsite1, site2.general1, site2.general2**.

How can I create these rules?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Any rules that are failing? Have you tried a different database structure?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm new about Firebase. I'm experienced about RDBMS but I need to use real-time database to do something like messaging. I mean, the server must send notification, not the client ask for it. 

My problem here is, the security. Other users have not to access others data. I've read some documentaries about it and found that I can check current node properties, not different node data.